# Reference Specific Commit in a Repo Without Podspec

Tags: cocoapods

With `cocoapods` I'd like to reference a specific commit (without tag) for a repo which does *not* have a Podspec file - namely `SBJSON`. How can I specify this? I tried:

```
pod 'SBJson', :podspec => 'https://raw.github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/master/SBJson/3.1/SBJson.podspec', :git => 'https://github.com/stig/json-framework.git', :commit => '5c4d5f7'
```

But I cannot both provide `:podspec` *and* `:git` with `:commit`. What can I do? Do I have to provide my own local `Podspec` file for this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off in the case of `SBJSON` it does have a podspec. You can see it in the [specs repo](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/tree/master/SBJson). You can use `pod search SBJSON` on the command line to see that there is one for it. One thing to keep in mind is that just because the library creator doesn't have the `.podspec` included in the repo doesn't mean it hasn't been contributed by the community.

But you would *have* to create a podspec for the repo otherwise. The podspec shows the CocoaPods tool how to include the library into your project.

Comment: I copied the mentioned `podspec` to my repo and adjusted the `:commit` parameter. Works fine.

Comment: @fabb you can actually use `pod 'SBJSON', :commit => 'foo'`

Comment: I tried `pod 'SBJson', :commit => 'cbdf88a'`, but the error `[!] Unknown external source parameters for 'SBJson': 'commitcbdf88a'` was output.

Comment: Check out the documentation [here](http://docs.cocoapods.org/podfile.html#pod) about the podfile flags. Especially the bottom few.

Comment: Yes, I know. But it doesn't say how to _reference a specific commit (without tag) for a repo which does not have a Podspec file_, as I asked in my question.

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer you cannot use a library that does not have an associated podspec file in the master repo. But you can use `pod 'AFNetworking', :git => 'https://github.com/gowalla/AFNetworking.git', :commit => '082f8319af'` to point to a specific fork & commit

Comment: `AFNetworking` is a bad example, as it does have a `podspec` file in the repo. I want to do the same thing with a repo *without* a podspec in it, as written in my question. Try `pod 'SBJson', :git => 'https://github.com/stig/json-framework.git', :commit => '5c4d5f7'`, it does not work. It says `No podspec found for 'SBJson' in /Users/fabian/dev/WillhabeniOS/Pods/SBJson/SBJson.podspec`.

Comment: Ah now I understand. Yes your first comment is what you should do here. Just alter the spec and move it to your own `~/.cocoapods/repos/mine/SBJSON/1.x/SBJSON.podspec`

Comment: BTW, the guys from CocoaPods also say it's not possible in another way, and this feature will not be implemented: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/1403